# SQL unpivot function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

i have a table with over 100 rows and 20 columns ( store, sales, size, profit etc.)  how can i  unpivot into just three columns ( store, metric , value)

current state

[image: current state]

future state

[image: future state]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: ms sql server is the DBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using `cross apply`:

```
select t.store, v.metric, v.value
from t cross apply
     (values ('size', size),
             ('sales', sales),
             ('profit', profit),
             . . .
     ) v(metric, value);
```

Note that this requires that the `value` column have compatible types.

Although you do have to list all the columns, you can generate the list using a query or a spreadsheet, simplifying the effort to write the query.